# Uncaught Error: Ziggy error: 'blog' parameter is required for route 'blogs.show'

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I am using inertia js with react in laravel 8, while showing my single-page blog with route it show the above error

In my route

```
Route::get('blogs/{blog:slug}', [BlogController::class, 'show'])->name('blogs.show');
```

In my controller

```
public function show(Blog $blog)
{
   return inertia('Blogs/Show', compact('blog'));
}
```

In my view

```
<Link href={route('blogs.show', props.blog.slug)} className="text-blue-500 inline-flex items-center md:mb-2 lg:mb-0">Learn More
   <svg className="w-4 h-4 ml-2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
       <path d="M5 12h14"/>
       <path d="M12 5l7 7-7 7"/>
   </svg>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly run `php artisan route:list` to ensure your route does not have extra parameters in it.

Even thou this code should work as the documentation specifies. I would suggest specifying the parameters to ensure its there and not another parameter is missing.

```
route('blogs.show', {slug: props.blog.slug})
```